# How can i update the value to use in other function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using useState for this object 'selected',  i want to get the updated value in this function verifyActive

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({ a: '', b: '' })
```

and i have a function that is active since a button

```
const setActive = (value) => {
    setSelected({ ...selected, b: value })
    verifyActive()
}

const verifyActive=()=>{
    console.log('selected', selected) // is not updated
}
...
console.log(selected) //here is value is updated
return (
  <button 
    onchange={(value) => { setActive(value) }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local const `selected` is never going to change, but what you can do is save the new state to a variable, and pass it in to verifyActive:

```
const setActive = (value) => {
  const newState = { ...selected, b: value };
  setSelected(newState);
  verifyActive(newState);
}

const verifyActive = (value) => {
  console.log('selected', value);
}
```

Comment: sorry but does not worked

Comment: is needed to pass by parameter verifyActive(newState); ?

Comment: Yes, setActive has the object, verifyActive needs the object, so you will need to pass it in.

Comment: is there another way to solve this?

Comment: When does `verifyActive` need to run? If it can wait until after the next time the component renders, you could put it in a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

change your setActive to this way

```
const setActive = (value) => {
    setSelected((prevSelected) => { ...prevSelected, b: value })
    verifyActive()
}
```